# Issues running maven project after installing jre 6

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My project was running successfully without any errors on local tomcat server 6 compiled with java 1.7 and jre 7. I wanted to run the same project with jre 6 and installed jre 6. But now it stopped running on both the jre versions. it gets stuck at

```
Mar 18, 2015 5:08:14 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool...
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing this to yourself? JRE 6 is seriously outdated.

Comment: @Bram Some issues with the project running on server. So I thought of compiling it with jre 6